# view don't render json appropriately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, view

I using rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.

My model Country has 3 attributes: id, name:string and flag:string.

The controller:

```
...
respond_to :html, :json
def index
  @countries = Country.all      
  respond_whit @countries.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
end
```

So, when I access countries.json in the browser it's show all attributes instead only id and name. I already tried redefine the method as_json like this:

```
def as_json(options = nil)
  {id: id, text: name}
end
```

but didn't work too.

Curiously, when I run as_json in the console it's work perfectly.

What is missing to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jbuilder to show the specific attributes

```
json.companies @companies.map { | company |

  {
    id: company.id,
    text: company.name

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know where and how I use this, sorry I'm newbie.

Comment: just create a index.json.jbuilder file in app/views/{controller name} folder

Comment: You're correct. I was generate model through scaffold and file index.json.jbuilder was automatic created and I didn't have notice. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
respond_with @countries, only: [:id, :name]
```

Comment: @user1704416 ok see if my update answer works for you

Comment: No, I don't think so. I have other model with the same code and it works. I guess I get crazy.

Comment: try @countries.to_a.as_json(only: [:id, :name])

Comment: I already had try that. Does it have to do with cache or something like that?

Comment: It make worse, now the attribute "id" is gone.